# Android Frequent Background Polling - CountDownTimer or JobScheduler

Tags: android, background-process

We have a "chat" SDK for lack of a better term, designed to drop into a host application and allow live chat sessions with an agent.  Part of that process is polling the server every few seconds *while a conversation is taking place* for new messages or information.  Since this is intended at least partially as a diagnostic aid, it is very desirable that this polling and conversation continue in the background.  Note that we have a defined start and end of a conversation, so this is not a boundless process.

Up until recently, this was implemented as a `BoundService` that was directly started (the conversation has to survive past being bound)  With the changes to Android 8.0, this no longer works.  The background service is terminated "shortly" after the application is put in the background.

My first attempt around it was to use a periodic `JobScheduler`, but that can't poll any more frequently than 15 min.

We're investigating options for supporting Android 8.0, and so far the easiest option seems to be to eliminate the background service and implement the polling using a `CountDownTimer` (more or less obviously on the main thread, but irrelevant because the work is actually handled in an AsyncTask)  This seems to be working fine, the polling continues until the conversation ends and everything is copacetic.

Should I change this to use a `JobScheduler` with a short timeout that just reschedules itself upon completion?

Another option might be a foreground `Service` containing the conversation itself, but that would entail quite a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need such short poll times, I would advise either you use the following

ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor
As per reading tour case, this seems the most suitable option as you need regular intervalic polling on a seperate thread. The ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor has a very easy implementation for this. Note the following code:

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10) //thread count
                .scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                    //Perform action; //Implement a runnable
                },1000, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
//1000 - The initial delay in milliseconds.
//10 - The number of minutes to keep polling.
```

All this happens on a separate thread, as you requested. `Executors` are a basic Java Framework Threading Primitive. The only downside is once the process is killed. The constant polling will die too.

For a more Android-Centric approach try an AlarmManager which can optionally survive process deaths even phone-reboots (only if you want, you must declare this in the manifest)

**[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)**

This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running.

Example Implementation

```
    Calendar repeatTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    repeatTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
    repeatTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,05);

    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, <YOURBROADCASTRECEIVER>.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,repeatTime.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Operation on a separate thread isn’t required as all that’s being done is to kick off an `AsyncTask` which runs out of a `ThreadPool`

Comment: So you would like an option to kick off the `AsyncTask` periodically? In that case both options I mentioned afford you that possibility. The alarm manager once you've implemented the broadcast receiver will run the code you want on your main thread by default. Two limitations I find with AsyncTask is that it is not Lifecycle aware, and work you throw onto it queues up sequentially (not maximizing multithreading), if any of the tasks throw an Exception, your app will crash